# Using a static recordset as temporary storage with field updates

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I'm calling a stored procedure to generate an ADO recordset and I'd like to be able to update the data before outputting it (but not write those updates back to the DB).

Is this even possible and if so, how?

I've tried a number of cursor and lock types but they either error out immediately or when I try to update a recordset field.

```
io_oRecordSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient
io_oRecordSet.Open oDataCmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdStoredProc
... iterate through RS ...
io_oRecordSet("myCol").value = "foo"
```

This one generate the following error

> Microsoft Cursor Engine error '80040e21'
>
> Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.

From what I've seen I suspect that ADO might not like that the data is coming from a stored procedure since it wouldn't know how to do a DB update.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely don't need to update the database, you can use a [disconnected Recordset](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184397). Just make sure you use a client-side cursor and set the Recordset's `ActiveConnection` property to `Nothing` after you open it.